# Ubuntu 20.10: Can not install intl extension

Tags: php, ubuntu, apt-get, intl

I'm trying to have an **intl** extension in my PHP on ubuntu.

I have uncommented **extension=intl** in php.ini and restarted apache.
However, I'm still getting an error in PHP:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

So I entered this directory (/usr/lib/php/20190902) and noticed that an intl extension is missing indeed. I've tried to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
```

but in both cases I'm getting errors like this:

```
ubuntu@vps-[vps-number]:/usr/lib/php/20190902$ sudo apt-get install php-intl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  php7.4-intl
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-intl php7.4-intl
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 47 not upgraded.
Need to get 125 kB of archives.
After this operation, 517 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 php7.4-intl amd64 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.2
Err:2 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy/universe amd64 php-intl all 2:7.4+76
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates/universe amd64 php7.4-intl amd64 7.4.9-1ubuntu1.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.4/php7.4-intl_7.4.9-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php-defaults/php-intl_7.4+76_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I have also tried to run `sudo apt-get update` as I found on StackOverflow, but I had this result:

```
ubuntu@vps-[vps-number]:/usr/lib/php/20190902$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:5 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease
Err:6 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
Err:7 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
Err:8 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.41 80]
Ign:9 https://packages.sury.org/php groovy InRelease
Err:10 https://packages.sury.org/php groovy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.93.2.243 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How to get this extension installed?

My system info:
**Operating System:** Ubuntu 20.10
**Kernel:** Linux 5.8.0-63-generic
**Architecture:** x86-64
**Virtualization:** kvm

Comment: You have an issue with your repositories i guess, try to check the sources.list to see if there is something wrong with it

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 has reached end of life, i think the sources.list file needs to change, try archive.ubuntu.com instead